# Is it possible to programatically alter tables with Core Data

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I'm working on a project in which I might need to change my local database, according to information fetched from a server.
I've read about Core Data, but from all I saw it uses a pre-defined database structures, and I haven't found a way to alter a table by code with it.
I was wondering - should I use Core Data for this use? or should I stick with low-level objective-c wrap for SQLite?
Tnx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to go ahead and say "no, that is not a good idea" mainly because core data requires a lot of generated code to work properly...code which is generated in the XCode environment, not in the application environment.

For example, if you come up with schema for your data, XCode creates data entity objects and links them in specific ways which you shouldn't tamper with. If you were to attempt to alter the schema in real time, you would have to effectively regenerate all those entities and their linkages...which seems impossible. In my experience, any core data schema change requires a clean, delete and reinstall of the application before it will run again as well as resetting the host device's data entirely in some cases to get rid of the old data.

So no...seems unlikely to work.